# How to Select Last Entry If None On Input Date SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a set of data that I am passing a user input of date to pull from a table.

What I am trying to do is setup up logic as such:

Here is the original table:

```
User    DATE_TIME        Value
HH1     5/20/2018 1:00    50
HH1     5/20/2018 10:00   50
HH1     5/20/2018 18:00   120
HH1     5/25/2018 12:00   10
HH1     5/26/2018 10:00   15
```

User passes 05/20/2018 into the sql query for DATE_TIME

The output is as follows:

```
User    DATE_TIME        Value
HH1     5/20/2018 1:00    50
HH1     5/20/2018 10:00   50
HH1     5/20/2018 18:00   120
```

Now the user passes 05/21/2018 into DATE_TIME

```
Result is nothing
```

What I am trying to accomplish is...if there are no results on the current day, then pull the latest value in the database, in this case:

```
User    DATE_TIME        Value
HH1     5/20/2018 18:00   120
```

I am not sure how to find this most recent value.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: you want answer in mysql or oracle??

Comment: I am using TOAD for Oracle to setup my sql

Comment: What does any of this have to do with `vba`? Perhaps you haven't noticed the tags that are automatically attached at the end of your post - or you didn't realize this website attaches somewhat random tags, so you must almost always override them manually?

Comment: What are the data types of `DATE_TIME` and `HOUR`? And why don't you keep both the date and the hour in a single column of data type `date`, as should always be done in Oracle?

Comment: I did not notice, will keep in mind.  I do have Date/Time in one column, but also broken out separately just thought it would be easier to do separated.

Comment: See below for comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my solution below, I named the base table `TBL` and I changed the name of the first column to `USR` since "user" is an Oracle keyword.

Most of the work is done in the subquery. Look at the `FROM` clause first: I cross-join to a small subquery that creates an actual date from the input (assumed to be given as a string in `MM/DD/YYYY` format). Depending on your application, you may be able to input a date directly and not have to convert to date in the query. One way or another, you should be able to use the input date.

The `WHERE` clause limits the rows to dates up to the input date given (with that date **included**). Then we rank the rows in *descending* order, but with a modification we make first: If there are any rows on the input date, their time-of-day component is truncated to zero. (The `DATE_TIME` value is replaced with the input date for those rows only.) So if there are any rows for the input date, all the rows for that date will get rank = 1, and all other rows will get higher ranks. However, if there are no rows for the input date, then the most recent row before that date will get rank = 1 (and *only* that row, assuming there are no duplicates in the `DATE_TIME` column).

So then the job of the outer query is easy: keep only the row OR ROWS where rank = 1. This means either ALL the rows for the input date (if there were any), or the single most recent row before that date.

The subquery-outer query structure cannot be avoided, because the WHERE clause is evaluated before the ranks can be calculated in the same query. If we want the `WHERE` clause to reference ranks, it must be in an outer query (at a higher level than the query that generates the ranks).

The query should be efficient, since the optimizer is smart enough to see we only want rank = 1 in the outer query, so it will not actually compute ALL the ranks (it will not fully order the subquery rows by `DATE_TIME`). And, of course, if there is an index on `DATE_TIME`, it will be used.

You didn't say anything about the role played by `USR`. If it plays no role, then the solution should work as-is. If you also input a `USR`, then add the filter in the `WHERE` clause of the subquery. If you need a result for each `USR` separately, for the same input date, add `PARTITION BY USR` in the analytic clause of the `RANK()` function.

```
select usr, date_time, value
from   (
         select usr, date_time, value,
                rank() over (order by case when date_time >= input_date then input_date 
                                           else date_time end desc) as rnk
         from   tbl cross join 
                (select to_date(:input_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy') as input_date from dual)
         where  date_time < input_date + 1
       )
where  rnk = 1
;
```

Comment: @KaushikNayak - yes... which is weird, since I tested the query on the OP's data and then I copied and pasted the query. On the other hand, my laptop is getting old - it does give me a lot of trouble with typing and editing text.

Comment: I am using app now , so didn't take the risk of editing it myself . +1 anyway !

Comment: This worked exactly as I expected!  Thank you very much.

Comment: Curious, how difficult would it be to modify query to pull like this for example pulling for 25th:  There is only data for 12:00 meaning 12:00 - 23:59 if covered by this value...however, there is nothing for 1:00 - 11:00.  How to pull the last value from 5/20 to cover 1:00 - 11:00 and then pull current day 5/25 12:00 data at same time.

Answer (score 1):

Below query will make use of window function ROW_NUMBER PARTITION BY ORDER BY. It will combine (UNION ALL) the records equal to input date OR if not found, get the rec with max date. Rownum =1 and rank=1 will only get the first record. If date is same with user input then the max date will be at the bottom and will not be selected. If date is not found then record with max date is the only record, thus will be shown. See demo at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/931c2/1.

```
SELECT usr as "user", date_time, valu as "value"
FROM (
SELECT usr, date_time, valu,
row_number() over (partition by trunc(date_time) 
order by date_time desc) as rnk
FROM TEST
WHERE to_char(DATE_TIME, 'yyyy-mm-dd') = '2018-05-21'
UNION ALL
SELECT usr, date_time, valu,
row_number() over (order by date_time desc) as rnk
FROM TEST) t
WHERE rnk = 1
AND rownum = 1;
```

Comment: This solution has two problems... first, if there is even one row with date equal to the input date, then the second branch of your UNION ALL should not be included in the result. Second (less serious - more easily fixed), the second branch is over all dates in the table; the OP only wanted rows BEFORE the input date.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly as hell, who knows how it'll behave on large tables (probably not very well), but - kind of works on a simple case (based on Oracle).

```
SQL> create table test (usern varchar2(3), date_time date, hour number, value number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test
  2    (select 'HH1', date '2018-05-20', 1, 50 from dual union
  3     select 'HH1', date '2018-05-20', 10, 50 from dual union
  4     select 'HH1', date '2018-05-20', 18, 120 from dual union
  5     select 'HH1', date '2018-05-25', 12, 10 from dual union
  6     select 'HH1', date '2018-05-26', 10, 15 from dual
  7    );

5 rows created.

SQL>
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from test t
  3  where t.date_time = (select max(t1.date_time) from test t1
  4                       where t1.usern = t.usern
  5                         and t1.date_time <= to_date('&&date_you_enter', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
  6                      )
  7    and t.hour = (select max(case when e.it_exists = 'Y' then t.hour
  8                                  else t2.hour
  9                             end)
 10                  from test t2 left join
 11                      (select t3.usern, 'Y' it_exists
 12                       from test t3
 13                       where t3.date_time = to_date('&&date_you_enter', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
 14                      ) e on e.usern = t2.usern
 15                 )
 16  order by t.date_time, t.hour;
Enter value for date_you_enter: 20.05.2018

USE DATE_TIME        HOUR      VALUE
--- ---------- ---------- ----------
HH1 20.05.2018          1         50
HH1 20.05.2018         10         50
HH1 20.05.2018         18        120

SQL> undefine date_you_enter
SQL> /
Enter value for date_you_enter: 21.05.2018

USE DATE_TIME        HOUR      VALUE
--- ---------- ---------- ----------
HH1 20.05.2018         18        120

SQL> undefine date_you_enter
SQL> /
Enter value for date_you_enter: 25.05.2018

USE DATE_TIME        HOUR      VALUE
--- ---------- ---------- ----------
HH1 25.05.2018         12         10

SQL>
```

Answer (score -1):

It will be helpful if you post your SQL Statement.  But try this

Select 
column1, column2,
FROM
YourTable
Where Date <= @dateInputByUserGoesHere

Comment: This has nothing to do with the OP's question. Also, the question is clearly tagged `oracle`, and there is no @ in Oracle names. Definite downvote for BOTH reasons.

Comment: @mathguy - you're pathetic.  There was no mention of Oracle by the person asking question.  He later added that.It had VBA tag. You mentioned it after which the person asking question changed the tags. My answer was very generic You seem to have nothing better to do in life than down voting people trying to help. Go F yourself.

Comment: Hey dude, the downvote was primarily for an answer that has nothing to do with the question the OP asked, regardless of database product. As for your language, watch it - I don’t mind it myself, but even so it will very likely get you thrown out from this site.

Comment: You don't like the answer ignore it. Why poking around and giving negative points? Why not mind your own business?  The idea behind giving @dateInputByUserGoesHere is to let the person know your value should go here. It is sort of a pseudo code not a concrete solution. I did not say this is the solution. I said try it. I clearly mentioned if he provides his statement it will help identify issue.